# Get list of CITIES from Shipping rates based on city

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

So, I was following this example on [How to change the city field to a dropdown by Jeroen](https://jeroensormani.com/changing-the-city-field-to-a-dropdown/) in my Billing/Shipping section of my site.

```
/**
 * Change the checkout city field to a dropdown field.
 */
function city_to_dropdown( $fields ) {
    $city_args = wp_parse_args( array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'options' => array(
            'amsterdam' => 'Amsterdam',
            'rotterdam' => 'Rotterdam',
            'den-haag'  => 'Den Haag',
            'utrecht'   => 'Utrecht',
            'leiden'    => 'Leiden',
            'groningen' => 'Groningen',
        ),
    ), $fields['shipping']['shipping_city'] );
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_city'] = $city_args;
    $fields['billing']['billing_city'] = $city_args; // Also change for billing field
    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'city_to_dropdown' );
```

Everything works as expected, but here is what I want to do different.

I want to be able to query all the list of cities from the from **shipping rates based on city** and display them in the dropdown code above.

[image]

So then I wouldn’t have to add the cities manually in multiple places. My list of cities will always be the cities added in using the **shipping rates based on city** functionality.

What do I need to do to be able to remove the manually entered cities and have something similar to the following :

```
‘options’ => get_list_cities_from_shipping_rate(),
```

### Question :

What [filters or hooks](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html) in woocommerce do I have to call to be able to return the list of cities in my function `get_list_cities_from_shipping_rate()` ?

I'm new to writing these custom codes in wordpress. Any help pointers on how to get this started would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You may encounter some trouble, here! Woocommerce's shipping zones allow the definition of regions which can be country, state, or postcode based. But I don't see *city* specifically in there anywhere. https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/setting-up-shipping-zones/

Comment: I was wondering if I could query the database table where the city values are stored when I enter them on **shipping rates based on city** and return it back.

Comment: Are you using https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-extra-flat-rate/, and if so, which version? If not, what plugin you used and what its version?

Comment: @SallyCJ Im using this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-advanced-free-shipping/ Version 1.0.14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function get_list_cities_from_shipping_rate( $rate_id ) {
    $cities = '';

    $key = '_wafs_shipping_method_conditions';
    $conditions = get_post_meta( $rate_id, $key, true );

    foreach ( (array) $conditions as $group ) {
        foreach ( (array) $group as $cond ) {
            if ( ! isset( $cond['condition'] ) ) {
                continue;
            }

            if (
                'city' === $cond['condition'] &&
                '==' === $cond['operator']
            ) {
                $cities .= $cities ? ', ' : '';
                $cities .= $cond['value'];
            }
        }
    }

    $cities = preg_split( '/, */', $cities );

    return array_unique( array_filter( $cities ) );
}
```

Things to note:

- On the *WooCommerce → Settings → Advanced Free Shipping* page, the `$rate_id` is the one after the `post=` as in `http://example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=123&action=edit`. Hover on the *Free shipping rates* table rows and you'd see the *Edit* URL having that `post` query.
- You must use the city's name and not its slug. E.g. `Den Haag` instead of `den-haag`. See the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9v35z.png) you provided.

Comment: I added your code but nothing happens. Can you tell me what the `$key = '_wafs_shipping_method_conditions';` is ? Is it a table in the database you are referencing to? And I tried printing `$conditions`, it does not return anything.

Comment: It is the name of the meta key where the plugin stores the rules you've specified. Can you actually post a direct link to the ZIP file of the plugin version 1.0.*14*?

Comment: I see. Try changing the value of `$key` to `_was_shipping_method_conditions` (note the `was` and `wafs`). That should work. If not, add `var_dump( $conditions );` after the `$conditions` declaration in the `function`, and share its output. And sorry, I should've asked for the ZIP file earlier on..

Comment: Nothing happens. when I do `var_dump( $conditions );` I get `bool(false)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170692/discussion-between-sally-cj-and-shabeer90).